# Can we use subsonic version 2.2 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, subsonic2.2

I extensively make use of Subsonic version 2.2 in my visual studio 2005 projects. I moved one of my projects to visual studio 2010. Upon compiling, it gives me host of errors pertaining to Subsonic.

Can't we use subsonic version 2.2 with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can.

What works great, with VS 2010 and VS 2012:

- Create a library project (DAL) with SubSonic and all generated and partial classes.
- Use a little batch script to generate the classes (`sonic.exe generate /out generated`) and execute it when rebuilding the DAL.

I'm not sure whether the BuildProvider used to autogenerate classes still works - I never used it.